# Detailed Explanation of Sonnet 55

Tags: shakespeare

Could anyone give me a line by line interpretation of Sonnet 55? I am having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! I'm sorry, but literary criticism is explicitly [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here: literary works are virtually by definition infinitely interpretable, so any adequate answer would be too long and too controversial for our Q&A format.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yeah, we should inform those morons at No Fear Shakespeare, they have no clue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broadly scoped.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Because we have way too many questions here about Shakespeare or, for that matter, about this or that language nuance that might be of interest to experts. I understand.

Comment: This question may be too broad for any [SE] community, but — am I missing/misunderstanding something? Isn’t this question a candidate for [Literature.SE](//literature.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Ricky Using 'we' without bothering to stick to the protocols of the site is hypocritical in my opinion. One point of grammar / semantics at a time has been the rule 'we' have had here for far longer than either of us has been a member. I won't stoop to downvote your reasonable (for another website dealing with this type of question)  answer, but your attitude will soon be flagged unless it changes. //  Is there a good reason why Hellion, choster and Rory Alsop haven't been castigated by you?

Comment: @Ricky I appreciated your answer, it taught me a few new things and I hope the OP appreciated your time and effort too. If the OP had asked about only two or three lines, and gave his interpretation, the question might have survived.

Comment: Where is the turn in Sonnet 55? Lines 8-9 or lines 11-12?

Answer (score 1):

Hardly his best sonnet, but here goes:

> Not marble nor the gilded monuments
>   Of princes shall outlive this pow'rful rhyme,

The marble of palaces and the gilded statues of rulers, though long-lasting, will not outlast these lines, the lines I'm about to write - about You [presumably the girl he loves].

> But you shall shine more bright in these conténts
>   Than unswept stone, besmeared with sluttish time.

On the contrary: You will shine more brightly than all that white stone the great buildings are made of: unattended stone is blackened by that big bad whore we know as Time.

> When wasteful war shall statues overturn,

When statues are knocked down and shattered by military activities

> And broils root out the work of masonry,

... and riots uproot all those great buildings ...

> Nor Mars his sword, nor war’s quick fire, shall burn
>   The living record of your memory.

Neither the God of War, Mars, with his flaming sword, nor the fire of war, will succeed in destroying your memory [preserved in this poem].

> 'Gainst death and all oblivious enmity
>   Shall you pace forth;

You will continue on despite death and ignorant aggression;

> ... your praise shall still find room
>   Even in the eyes of all posterity
>   That wear this world out to the ending doom.

There will always be enough time and space in this world for all posterity, up until the end of the world, to admire You.

> So till the judgment that yourself arise,
>   You live in this, and dwell in lovers' eyes.

Thus until Judgment Day, when You get to be raised from the dead along with all the others, You will continue to be alive in the eyes of those who are in love and have read this poem.

Comment: Where is the turn in Sonnet 55? Is it between line 8-9 or 11-12? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea. Some of those terms, and the concepts they're supposed to represent, are awfully contrived and silly.

Comment: @AlanTam: My pleasure.